# Xcode - Update UITableView (xml data from server) every day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, notifications

For my new iPhone Application (Xcode 4.3.2), i want to update my UITable (xml data from server) every day, even if the application running in the background. Which method i need to follow. Could you please guide me?

Comment: you can't. Your app can run max 30 minutes in background, so you will have to start it every day to update it every day

Comment: Also, why not just update the data when the app is launched? What will you do with the data if the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you another option, send Local notification daily to your app and when user clicks on notification application starts then update data from server.

This option is if you want to update daily.

other wise it is not necessary to update data when app is in background, you can update it when ever it is launched

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications may be another answer you want to look into.  I have an app on my device which appears to use push notifications for a similar purpose (updating the app with new data daily).

Comment: Thank you RonLugge. When we use push notification, the uitable data will update only when we open the application, not in the background right?

Comment: Not sure, I don't use push notifications very often.